# Is it possible to change dots size on LineChart?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am creating a `CombinedChart` with [`ios-chart`](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library and I would like to change the dots size (data markers) of the `LineChart`. I would like to make them smaller because they are very big in comparison of the data. You can see an screenshot below:

[image]

Is it possible to change the size of that data markers? I could not find anything on the web.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-c you can change the data marker radius from a LineChartDataSet
simply with
`yourDataSet.circleRadius = 1.0`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of the circles with the next line:

```
 yourline.circleRadius = CGFloat.init(4.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 3rd party framework. You can modify it to suit your needs.

In particular, it seems you would have to modify this file:

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Components/MarkerImage.swift

If you run into any further difficulties you should ask a new question.